# Use pyvmomi to add managment service to vmnikc?

Tags: python, vmware, pyvmomi

Good day,

I am trying to use pyvmomi to build out a network infrastructure that includes a closed network with a virtual nic to access the ESXi web management interface. Thus far, I have successfully added a virtual nic with `host.configManger.networkSystem.AddVirtualNic` but unable to locate where to add the management service to this nic.  When attempting to use `host.configManager.networkSystem.AddServiceConsoleVirtualNic`, the following error is returned: "The operation is not supported on the object." I do not know for sure if the AddServiceConsoleVIrtualNic is the correct route, but I figured it was worth trying. Both of the above methods do not appear to allow for this to happen.

While searching the internet, I can not seem to find a good example to make this happen.

Can anyone point me in the best direction to add the Management Service to a vmnic?